# WSDiscovery with specific port

Tags: python, camera, ip-camera, onvif, python-onvif

I'm using python WSDiscovery to discover cameras on my network, using Onvif. It used to work great. Problem is that the new camera I have has onvif on different port (8899) and I cannot change it.

I was able to detect camera using `onvif-audit.js` from https://github.com/RogerHardiman/onvif-audit where I can put -P parameter to specify port.

I cannot use npm on my device, so question is, if it is possible to change port that is used by WSDiscovery lib?